# Instance variable not availabe after a render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a sign-up and log-in page that has some images from already signed up users. I have a sessions and user controller to log-in and sign-up users respectively to my application.

sessions controller

```
    def new
      @users = User.last(3)
    end

    def create
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in user
        redirect_back_or user
      else
        flash.now[:error] = "Wrong email/password combination"
        render 'new'
      end
    end
```

I then use the instance variable @user to display the images of the lates 3 users. This also applies to my user controller. I have a partial `slider` in my "new" view

_slider.html.erb

```
    <% for user in @users do %>
            <div class="item">
                <%= image_tag user.photos.first.image.url(:large) %>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4><%= user.name %></h4>
                    <p><%= user.tagline %></p>
                </div>
            </div>
    <% end %>
```

This works fine in both the sign-up and log-in page not until the form for sign-up/log-in contains errors. I get this error thrown `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`. I think the `@user` variable is not available after I render the page.

How do I make it available after I re-render the new action? or how should I go about it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each http request is stateless and doesn't know about the previous values (stateless).
Therefore if the partial is rendered it needs `@users` and new action needs `@users` as well.
So, what you need is in controller `before_filter` or set/initialize the `@users` object from params[:xx]

```
before_filter: initialize_values
def initialize_values
  @users = User.last(3)
end
```

Comment: this is true but you don't want the extra query when the session create succeeds.

Comment: Does that answer your question though? You essentially wanted how to make instance variable available to your actions(if not clarify it please).

Answer (score 1):

on the else block, you need to declare the `@users` variable because you are rendering the new template.

```
else
  @users = User.last(3)
  flash.now[:error] = "Wrong email/password combination"
  render 'new'
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works fine but I want to re-use the `@users` variable across various controllers so I went with @m-abshir method to avoid repetition

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgott to use the @: use @user not user